# How to get custom headers in react javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, header

I'm new in fronted and I'm trying to get custom headers from backend rest/api.
The backend send the headers correctly as can i check with postman, I even create a mockable and I can see the custom headers.
But when I do the code in react. I can't see them

`return fetch(url, options).then(workResponse);
function workResponse(response) {return response.headers;}`

I console log the body and I can see the response.body correctly.
But when I try to access to response.headers.keys(). And then head.next(), i can only see these 2 keys, not my custom ones.

`{done: false, value: "cache-control"}
{done: false, value: "content-type"}`

Thanks!

Comment: Tried using `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` ? Read about it and see if you can get the headers after adding it.

Comment: It works perfect thanks @Panther. I had to set that in the backend.

Comment: Hey @Panther, consider transforming your comment into a response

Answer (score -1):

In Python you can use the after_request hook:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', '*')
    return response
```